# From Adam to Moshe Rabbeinu

Tags: torah-study, moshe-rabbeinu, abraham

I noticed interesting parallels between Adam, Noah, Abraham and Moshe.
When Hashem was angry on humans sins and wanted to punish human or humanity, we can notice different behavior from Adam to Moshe.

Adam:
Bereshit 3:11-12 when Hashem is angry, Adam complains about his wife

> וַיֹּ֕אמֶר מִ֚י הִגִּ֣יד לְךָ֔ כִּ֥י עֵירֹ֖ם אָ֑תָּה הֲמִן־הָעֵ֗ץ אֲשֶׁ֧ר צִוִּיתִ֛יךָ לְבִלְתִּ֥י אֲכׇל־מִמֶּ֖נּוּ אָכָֽלְתָּ׃
>
> וַיֹּ֖אמֶר הָֽאָדָ֑ם הָֽאִשָּׁה֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר נָתַ֣תָּה עִמָּדִ֔י הִ֛וא נָֽתְנָה־לִּ֥י מִן־הָעֵ֖ץ וָאֹכֵֽל׃

Noah. Bereshit 6:13

> וַיֹּ֨אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֜ים לְנֹ֗חַ קֵ֤ץ כׇּל־בָּשָׂר֙ בָּ֣א לְפָנַ֔י כִּֽי־מָלְאָ֥ה הָאָ֛רֶץ חָמָ֖ס מִפְּנֵיהֶ֑ם וְהִנְנִ֥י מַשְׁחִיתָ֖ם אֶת־הָאָֽרֶץ׃

And it says Bereshit 6:22

> וַיַּ֖עַשׂ נֹ֑חַ כְּ֠כֹ֠ל אֲשֶׁ֨ר צִוָּ֥ה אֹת֛וֹ אֱלֹהִ֖ים כֵּ֥ן עָשָֽׂה׃

So Noah didn't say anything at all to Hashem. Just did so. But we know, Noah was a tzadik!

Abraham. Bereshit 18:22-24

> וַיִּפְנ֤וּ מִשָּׁם֙ הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֔ים וַיֵּלְכ֖וּ סְדֹ֑מָה וְאַ֨בְרָהָ֔ם עוֹדֶ֥נּוּ עֹמֵ֖ד לִפְנֵ֥י יְהֹוָֽה׃
>
> וַיִּגַּ֥שׁ אַבְרָהָ֖ם וַיֹּאמַ֑ר הַאַ֣ף תִּסְפֶּ֔ה צַדִּ֖יק עִם־רָשָֽׁע׃
>
> אוּלַ֥י יֵ֛שׁ חֲמִשִּׁ֥ים צַדִּיקִ֖ם בְּת֣וֹךְ הָעִ֑יר הַאַ֤ף תִּסְפֶּה֙ וְלֹא־תִשָּׂ֣א לַמָּק֔וֹם לְמַ֛עַן חֲמִשִּׁ֥ים הַצַּדִּיקִ֖ם אֲשֶׁ֥ר בְּקִרְבָּֽהּ׃

We can see Abraham is trying to save people.

And Moshe at Exodus 32:10-11

> וְעַתָּה֙ הַנִּ֣יחָה לִּ֔י וְיִֽחַר־אַפִּ֥י בָהֶ֖ם וַאֲכַלֵּ֑ם וְאֶֽעֱשֶׂ֥ה אוֹתְךָ֖ לְג֥וֹי גָּדֽוֹל׃
>
> וַיְחַ֣ל מֹשֶׁ֔ה אֶת־פְּנֵ֖י יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהָ֑יו וַיֹּ֗אמֶר לָמָ֤ה יְהֹוָה֙ יֶחֱרֶ֤ה אַפְּךָ֙ בְּעַמֶּ֔ךָ אֲשֶׁ֤ר הוֹצֵ֙אתָ֙ מֵאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֔יִם בְּכֹ֥חַ גָּד֖וֹל וּבְיָ֥ד חֲזָקָֽה׃

Moshe is begging to Hashem to save people.

We can see clear growth from Adam to Moshe about caring of people.
Where Adam care only about himself and complained about wife.

Noah who was tzadik, but didn't ask anything for people.

Abraham who cared about people and tried to save them.

And Moshe Rabbeinu who was begging to Hashem to save people.

Is there any other parallels that are in Torah are growing since Adam to Moshe Rabbeinu?

Comment: To be fair, Adam didn't have a whole nation to care about...

Comment: It's an interesting thing you've noticed. It would be good to find a source that has also spotted this and discusses it as there could be other interpretations, such as what @Dov might be alluding to.

Comment: According to tradition, Noah built the ark for 400 years, warning people of their impending doom all the while but they wouldn’t listen. The difference between Noah and Abraham was, thatNoah had too much faith and didn’t question God whereas Abraham did struggle with God.

Comment: @TurkHill there are also sources that discuss the fact that Noach did not urge people to do teshuva, to let go of their beastly behaviour and turn to G-d. Avraham did "spread the word".

Comment: @Shmuel Jews should be like Abraham and “spread the word.” In other words, make converts.

Comment: Yes, and some meforshim say that is exactly what Noach did not do.

Comment: @Shmuel Yes, we agree.

Answer (score 0):

This is brought in at least a few places in the Holy Zohar:

Zohar I:105b (Wayera)

"And **Abraham** approached and said, Willst Thou destroy the righteous with the wicked?"
Rabbi Yehudah said: Who has ever seen a loving father like **Abraham**? Come and behold --
By **Noah** it's written (Gen. 6:13), "And Elkym said to Noah, The End of all flesh is come before Me ... make thyself an ark of Gofer-acacia tree" -- and he just keeps quiet and says nothing to Him. He doesn't ask for mercy. But **Abraham**, when the Holy Blessed One told him, "This outrage of Sodom and Gamorrah is just too great ... I will go down and see" etc. -- immmediately it's written, "And **Abraham** approached and said, Really wouldst Thou destroy the righteous with the wicked?!"

```
"ויגש אברהם ויאמר האף תספה צדיק עם רשע" -- אמר רבי יהודה, מאן חמא אבא דרחמנותא כאברהם, תא חזי בנח כתיב (בראשית ו יג) ויאמר אלהי"ם לנח קץ כל בשר בא לפני וגו', עשה לך תיבת עצי גפר, ואשתיק ולא אמר ליה מידי, ולא בעא רחמי, אבל אברהם בשעתא דאמר ליה קב"ה זעקת סדום ועמורה כי רבה וגו', ארדה נא ואראה וגו', מיד כתיב ויגש אברהם ויאמר האף תספה צדיק עם רשע.
```

Rabbi Elazar said, Even **Abraham** didn't do perfectly like he could and ought have. Noah did not one more thing neither [pleading] nor any [action]. Abraham requested proper justice like it ought to be, that the innocent not die with the wicked, starting with 50 and stopping after 10, stopping there and completing no more, for he's not asking mercy either way, because **Abraham** said, I do not want to demand reward for my actions) [perhaps this means to say that above 50 would not need his request, whereas below 10 would be already beyond justice proper, more than he is asking].
But who did do perfectly right? That's **Moses**! For as soon as the Holy Blessed One said (Ex. 32:8), "They have turned quickly from the way ... they have made them a molten Calf and prostrated before it" -- immediately what is written? -- And **Moses** totally besought the Face of the LORD His God" etc. -- to the extent that he says, "Now swear Thou willst forgive their deviousness - and if not then so I swear - wipe me out from Thy book that Thou hast written!" And even though every single one of them was deviant, he did not more from there until He told him, "I have forgiven per how thou hast spoken."
But **Abraham** paid no mind except if there be righteous people there, otherwise not at all. So for this reason there has never in the world been a mortal that defended his generation like **Moses**, who is the Raaya Meheimna, Faithful Shepherd!

```
אמר רבי אלעזר, אוף אברהם לא עבד שלימו כדקא יאות, נח לא עביד מידי לא האי ולא האי, אברהם תבע דינא כדקא יאות, דלא ימות זכאה עם חייבא, ושארי מחמשים עד עשרה, עבד ולא אשלים, דלא בעא רחמי בין כך ובין כך, דאמר אברהם לא בעינא למתבע אגר עובדי, אבל מאן עבד שלימו כדקא יאות, דא משה, דכיון דאמר קב"ה (שמות לב ח) סרו מהר מן הדרך וגו', עשו להם עגל מסכה וישתחוו לו, מיד מה כתיב ויחל משה את פני יהו"ה אלקיו וגו', עד דאמר ועתה אם תשא חטאתם, ואם אין מחני נא מספרך אשר כתבת, ואע"ג דכלהו חטו, לא זז מתמן עד דאמר ליה סלחתי כדברך, אבל אברהם לא אשגח אלא אי אשתכח בהו זכאי, ואם לאו לא, ועל דא לא הוה בעלמא בר נש דיגין על דריה כמשה, דאיהו רעיא מהימנא.
```

---

Z. Chadash 29a (!)

Rabbi Yochanan said, Come and see what's the difference between the Tzaddikim we used to have in Yisrael versus later (!), and versus **Noah**.
**Noah** did not defend his generation, and **Abraham** did not pray for his. For when the Holy Blessed One told **Abraham**, "The outrage of Sodom and Gomorrah is just too great" -- immediately "... and Abraham approached and said."  He poured out a great deal of speech before the Holy Blessed One, to the extent that he asked if there are ten righteous people there, He should atone for the whole generation for their sake. Now **Abraham** thought there were 10 in the city, with Lot and his wife, sons and daughters and sons-in-law. That's why he prayed no more.

אָמַר רִבִּי יוֹחָנָן, בֹּא וּרְאֵה מַה בֵּין הַצַּדִּיקִים שֶׁהָיוּ לְיִשְׂרָאֵל אַחַר כַּךְ, וּבֵין נֹחַ. נֹחַ לֹא הֵגִין עַל דּוֹרוֹ, וְלֹא הִתְפַּלֵּל עָלָיו כְּאַבְרָהָם. דְּכֵיוָן דְּאָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְאַבְרָהָם, זַעֲקַת סְדוֹם וַעֲמוֹרָה כִּי רָבָּה, מִיָּד וַיִּגַּשׁ אַבְרָהָם וַיֹּאמַר. וְהִרְבָּה דְבָרִים כְּנֶגֶד הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא, עַד שֶׁשָּׁאַל שֶׁאִם יִמְּצָא שָׁם עֲשָׂרָה צַדִּיקִים, שֶׁיְכַפֵּר לְכָל הַדּוֹר בִּשְׁבִילָם, וְחָשַׁב אַבְרָהָם שֶׁהָיוּ י' בָּעִיר, עִם לוֹט וְאִשְׁתּוֹ וּבָנָיו וּבְנוֹתָיו, וַחֲתָנָיו, וְלָכֵן לֹא הִתְפַּלֵּל יוֹתֵר.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that God changes a bit between the time of Abraham and the time of Moses.

In Genesis 18:22-32, God reveals to Abraham that He will not destroy a nation if there is ten righteous people living there.

But in Numbers 16:20-22, its implied that God will destroy Israel due to the sins of Korah and his group. Implying the inverse of Genesis 18:22-32.

Exodus 33:5 could also imply the same thing as Numbers 16:20-22.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150025/discussion-on-answer-by-taylor-from-adam-to-moshe-rabbeinu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.